# Loading code from editor into PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just started using PyCharm, and am consistently pleasantly surprised by its tools and configurability.  I know that in PyCharm, you can load code from the editor into a Python console (see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html). However, the remote console I'm using in PyCharm is very slow.

If I access python on the remote machine directly via ssh, it has no performance issues.  As such, I'd like to just open the remote version of python via PyCharm's Terminal, and execute code in the terminal from my editor.

However, I haven't found any key bindings (or options) that let me automatically load code -- it's a manual copy and past process for now.  When I try to create a keyboard shortcut to do this, the option isn't available.  Is there a method to create a keyboard shortcut to load code from the editor into the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to create such a shortcut by yourself is by writing a plugin to PyCharm. PyCharm plugins are written in Java, so I don't know whether this sounds like an appealing option for you. Alternatively, you can file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ asking for this feature to be added.

Note that you can set up a run configuration that will run your code for you on a remote interpreter without going through a console. Have you tried this? Is it also slow?

Comment: OK.  I think I'll put the feature request in.