# PyCharm equivalent to VSCode's "Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: pycharm

Does PyCharm have an equivalent to VSCode's "Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal" keyboard shortcut? I'd like to be able to highlight code and press Shift + Enter and have it automatically copy-pasted into PyCharm's Terminal. This seems to have been asked [8 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570666/loading-code-from-editor-into-pycharm-terminal), but I'm wondering if it might have become possible in the meantime.